# I am using ng-click and ng-show for pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am using ng-click and ng-show for pagination. In this case it keeps on creating new pages in both direction when ever buttons are clicked i.e it keeps on creating blank pages. It should stop at first and last page respectively. Here I have created three sub-pages for pagination the buttons should play only for this three sub pages.
Looking forward for any help.
thank you.

```
    <div class="container" ng-app="tabApp">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="TabController">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li>
                    <a href ng-click="setTab(tab+1)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Next</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href ng-click="setTab(tab-1)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Back</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div ng-show="isSet(1)">
                    <h1>Home page</h1>
                    <p>Welcome to the website!</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="isSet(2)">
                    <h1>Profile page</h1>
                    <p>Profile information</p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="isSet(3)">
                    <h1>Messages</h1>
                    <p> Some messages </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('tabApp', [])
        .controller('TabController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.tab = 1;

            $scope.setTab = function(newTab) {
                $scope.tab = newTab;
            };

            $scope.isSet = function(tabNum) {
                return $scope.tab === tabNum;
            };
        }]);

</script>
```

[I have created a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjrLNq?editors=1010)

Comment: Well, hideor disable our links if they point to unexisting pages. Note that what you'e doing here is not pagination. Pagination is this: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination. What you should probably do for this is to use a router, and have a real menu pointing to the actual pages (welcome, profile, messages) rather than to unknown pages (next, previous).

Comment: thanks for the help